# A big query about Jquery and gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have desgining gridview ,in which i have applied quicksearch function of jquery for filtering the gridview control and also i have applied sorting and paging.with normal searching, jquery function working properly but the problem is,whenever I use paging means whenever the gridview page_index is changed the function stopped his working. Is there any solution available for this problem or it could't be done?
 My quicksearch function is like that:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                $('input#TextBox1').quicksearch('table#grid tbody tr');
                });     
 </script>
```

amd my paging logic is like:-

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {          
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;           
            GridView1.DataBind();
            BindData();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(tableId, tableId.GetType(), "QuickSearch", "$('input#TextBox1').quicksearch('table#grid tbody tr');", true);`

to "GridView1_PageIndexChanging" (assuming you're using a scriptmanager).

Comment: thanx for your comment,but yet, it is not working and i am actually using update panal.